# openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac and JAVA solution differ

Tags: java, command, sha256, hmac, hmacsha1

I want to replicate:

```
echo -n "a" | openssl dgst -binary -sha256 -hmac "a"
```

in Groovy (Java). 
So far I've done this:

```
def sha = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256")
SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec("a".getBytes(), "HmacSHA256")
sha.init(secret_key)
def shaCrypted = new String(sha.doFinal('a'.getBytes()))
println(shaCrypted)
```

but unfortunately I don't get the same results.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the results you got in each? Can you paste the output please

Comment: i'm getting same results..  3ecf5388e220da9e0f919485deb676d8bee3aec046a779353b463418511ee622

Comment: print hex and compare `echo -n "a" | openssl dgst -binary -sha256 -hmac "a" | xxd -p`